# Query to include all transactions for current day + next day until certain time

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, time

I am having trouble generating a query for all transactions of the current day + 3 hours past midnight

This is a snippet of my query

```
where Date between '1-May-2018' and '2-May-2018' and Time <= '1754-01-01 03:00:00'
```

I want ALL transactions of 1 May 2018 and only transactions until 3am for 2 May.
How do I write this query?

Note that Date and Time are separate columns:

Sample of Date Column : 2018-10-19 00:00:00.000
Sample of Time Column : 1754-01-01 00:12:58.247

Rather than filter only on the Date column, do we need to filter on the Time column as well?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using SQL Server you need the following WHERE clause:

```
WHERE CAST(Date AS DATE) = CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) OR (
      CAST(Date AS DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)) AND
      CAST(Time AS TIME) <= '03:00:00'
)
```

Comment: Hi Salman,I tried to use the second query(Current_Date),SQL tells me that CURRENT_DATE is not a built-in function so I did this Date = CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) .And it was ok.Now when I try to use INTERVAL 1 day..SQL says invalid column

Comment: Oh wait... are you saying the question was about **SQL SERVER**?

Comment: I am running this query using MS SSMS v 14

Comment: @Sequel3 see revised answer.

Answer (score 3):

use below condition in where condition

```
where date='2018-05-01' OR (date='2018-05-02' and TIME(time)<='03:00:00')
```

Comment: Thanks but I have a seperate column called Time,The filter should be applied in the time column?

Comment: @Sequel3 then put conditon  time column going to edited answer

Comment: @Sequel3 what is the data type of your time column

Comment: WHERE Date BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-02'
AND Time between '1754-01-01 07:00:00.247' and '1754-01-01 03:00:00.247'                                 like this??

Comment: @Sequel3 where date>='2018-05-01' and date<='2018-05-02'
 and cast(time as time)<='03:00:00' use this condition it should work

Comment: @Sequel3 i edited answer could you please check this

Answer (score 2):

Using Between operator:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE date  BETWEEN '2018-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-05-02 03:00:00';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(date, ' ', time), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '2018-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-05-02 03:00:00';
```

Also: what type is the time column?